# Strange problem with load() and iframe (dojo)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dojo, load

I have I really big problem in this website http://emprego.xtreemhost.com/log/emprego.php

To see the problem you need to click on register (green button) and open the Firefox (I tested in Firefox 4).

If I do the same in chrome none scroll is created, but in Firefox, the registration page has a frame in the bottom of the page - is created a horizontal scroll.  I want to avoid the scroll and `overflow: hidden` is bad practice in this case.

Any ideas? I can't understand what is happening.

cause of the problem:    `var anim1b = new dojox.charting.action2d.Tooltip(chart1, "default");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in response to my question

i need to import the themes in the principal file that made the load()

solved